# Size doesn't matter

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

It's not the size that matters; it's how you use it. That being said, I have no use for these size-related tags:

- [size](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/size) (155)
- resize (207) (merged into [size](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/size))
- filesize (96) (merged into [size](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/size))
- folder-size (40) (merged into [size](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/size))

Comment: Mark your own question as [meta-tag:status-planned]! In other words, I agree with you.

Comment: TWSS!? Really!!!?

Comment: Merge/Synonimise them all to [size] to make it easier to burn them.

Comment: You know that it should be "Size matters not", right?

Comment: @Oliver - If you can, mark this as status-planned so it'll appear in the [Tag Cleanup Weekend](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8523/tag-cleanup-weekend-logistics?cb=1) list tomorrow

Comment: @Robotnik Good call

Comment: Getting ready for the cleanup weekend, could we merge the 4 tags so it is easier to clean? (and see progress in this question)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took a surprising chunk of a weekend, but size in fact matters not.